# What does JavaScript element.style='whatever' do to the html?

Tags: javascript, html

Does it enclose the element within a SPAN element with the given style or does it just assign the style to the attributes of the element itself? How about when I do element.style.border='1px solid red'? Does it depend on the browser or is there a rule?

Comment: "Does it enclose the element in a with the given style", hmm? :)

Comment: It adds to the element's style attribute.

Comment: he changed it, now i get what he meant... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styling would be assigned to the element's style attribute. For example:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('outlined');
myDiv.style.border='1px solid red';
```

Would turn `<div id="outlined"></div>` into:

```
<div id="outlined" style="border: 1px solid red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

It always assigns them to the element's style itself. I know of no browser that would introduce additional HTML elements into the DOM after setting the  `style` property.

Answer (score 1):

It just adds/changes the style attribute of the element in question, no other elements are created ever